# How to refresh just entity children without refreshing entire entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a pretty clean cut PARENT-CHILD case scenario in the DB, which is reflected in their corresponding entity objects:

**Parent:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_PARENT")
@NamedQueries(...)
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Child> childList;

    ...

    public List<Child> getChildren() {

        if(this.childList != null) {
            Collections.sort(this.childList);
        }

        return this.childList;
    }
```

**Child:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_CHILD")
@NamedQueries(...)

public class Child implements Serializable, Comparable<Child> {

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Parent parent;
```

As the loading of the child data is performed by the `JPA` framework as specified by the above annotations, I do not need to specify a method to load the data -- when `Parent` is loaded, its `Child`ren are loaded automatically.

However, I am looking for a way to refresh the children on demand without calling for a refresh of the whole parent.  When I call `getChildren()` on an existing parent, the method doesn't actually refresh the children as of the time of the request but just reuses the previously loaded and cached data.  Can I somehow induce a refresh on just the children without reloading the whole parent object?

We are using straight `JPA` but, as I understand, it utilizes some `Hibernate` libraries in the backend.

Comment: I could if I were inside a transaction that also loaded the data but since I'm dealing with session data that was loaded before being transacted upon so at that time I need a refresh, the entities are already detached so this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could refresh the children explicitly:

```
for (Child child : parent.getChildren()) {
   entityManager.refresh(child);
}
```